How to get the memory usage of a windows service in C++?
I'm looking for an example to get the memory usage of a service on windows using in C++.
I have searched this forum, Google and Microsoft documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Services/services
But I have not found this information at the moment.
Does anyone know how to do it?
This is my code to get the PID of the service.
Use this command to compile with Visual Studio:
cl /EHsc TheProgram.cpp Advapi32.lib

Include these libraries:
#include <windows.h>   
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <winsvc.h>

Find Services and print it on the screen using this function:
int FindServices(const std::string &ServiceNameToFind)
{
    SC_HANDLE hSCM = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);  
    if (hSCM == NULL)return 0;
    
    DWORD bufferSize = 0;
    DWORD requiredBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD totalServicesCount = 0;
    
    EnumServicesStatusEx( hSCM, 
        SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,
        SERVICE_WIN32,
        SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
        nullptr, 
        bufferSize,
        &requiredBufferSize,
        &totalServicesCount,
        nullptr,
        nullptr );

    std::vector<BYTE> buffer( requiredBufferSize );
    EnumServicesStatusEx( hSCM, 
        SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,
        SERVICE_WIN32,
        SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
        buffer.data(), 
        buffer.size(),
        &requiredBufferSize,
        &totalServicesCount,
        nullptr,
        nullptr );


    int result = 0;

    LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS services = reinterpret_cast<LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS>( buffer.data() );      
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < totalServicesCount; ++i )
    {           
        
        ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS service = services[i];  

        std::string CurrentServiceName(service.lpServiceName);              
        std::size_t found = CurrentServiceName.find(ServiceNameToFind);         
        if (found==std::string::npos) continue;         
        
        DWORD processID = service.ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId;
        std::cout <<service.lpServiceName<<" "<< processID <<std::endl;         

        result++;   
    }

    CloseServiceHandle( hSCM );
    return result;
}

Entry point:
int main( void )
{       
    std::string ServiceName("TheService");
    FindServices(ServiceName);
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

Thank you so much!!

EDITED

In the comments they have asked me to include here my attempt to use the GetProcessMemoryInfo() function.
I used this function. But it doesn't work with services. Because OpenProcess( ) returns a null handler.
void PrintMemoryInfo( DWORD processID )
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;

    hProcess = OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID );
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        {
         return; std::cout<< "OpenProcess() FAIL ->" <<GetLastErrorStdStr() <<std::endl;
        }

    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
    {
        std::cout<< "PageFaultCount:                ->" << pmc.PageFaultCount <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< "PeakWorkingSetSize:            ->" << pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< "WorkingSetSize:                ->" << pmc.WorkingSetSize <<std::endl;  
        std::cout<< "QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage:       ->" << pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< "QuotaPagedPoolUsage:           ->" <<  pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage <<std::endl;    
        std::cout<< "QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage:     ->" <<  pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< "QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage:         ->" <<  pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage <<std::endl;    
        std::cout<< "PagefileUsage:                 ->" <<  pmc.PagefileUsage <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< "PeakPagefileUsage:             ->" <<  pmc.PeakPagefileUsage <<std::endl;      
        
        
 );
    }

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

The GetLastError() function always returns "access denied", even if I run the executable with administrator permissions.
std::string GetLastErrorStdStr()
{
  DWORD error = GetLastError();
  if (error)
  {
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD bufLen = FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        error,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );
    if (bufLen)
    {
      LPCSTR lpMsgStr = (LPCSTR)lpMsgBuf;
      std::string result(lpMsgStr, lpMsgStr+bufLen);
      
      LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

      return result;
    }
  }
  return std::string();
}


Although really for me a solution in either of the two languages ​​would be a valid answer. For me the important thing is to get the memory usage in C or C++... but I respect the community rules... I'm sorry!!

The Service API doesn't keep track of memory usage. Perhaps you are looking for something like GetProcessMemoryInfo()?

Yes... something similar to that. The problem is that the GetProcessMemoryInfo() function does not work with services. Because OpenProcess() does not get a valid handler for the service. (Process -> HANDLE, Services ->  SC_HANDLE). Maybe if I can convert SC_HANDLE to HANDLE it will work. But I haven't gotten it yet. Thank you very much for helping.

An SCM service handle is not a process handle, you can't convert one to the other. But since you already have the Process ID of the service, just open a process handle directly via OpenProcess().

YES, I tried. But OpenProcess() returns a NULL handler

Then you likely didn't use it correctly. Please [edit] your question to include the code you attempted.

OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID ) --> Maybe something wrong here?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Ok... will edit it and include it

Ok, It's done. I edited the question and included my attempt to use OpenProcess()

The code you showed doesn't include the change I suggested earlier. You are asking OpenProcess() for more permissions than you actually need.

Side note: "memory usage" is not just a simple number. There's both allocated (virtual) memory size and resident memory size. There's also how much has potentially been paged out...

I'm lost... What change did you suggest?

I'm trying other flags... like these... but none of them work... some help would be nice.  OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | READ_CONTROL , FALSE, processID );

Yes, I want to get all the values ​​if possible. Thank you very much  @Jusper Juhl

I got it!! Thank you very much for your help!!

After a long time testing flags I managed to get it working.
In order to read the memory you must use this flag.
PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
like this:
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION , FALSE, processID );

AND execute it with administrator permissions.
